# Matplotlib Percentages incorrectly calculating

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have some code which is being used to analyse response survey results.

The code itself runs without issue, but I wanted to amend it slightly to include the percentage number at the end of the graph bar.

The code that I am using is as follows:

```
    for p in ax.patches:
        percentage ='{:,.0f}%'.format(p.get_width())
        width, height =p.get_width(),p.get_height()
        x=p.get_x()+width+0.02
        y=p.get_y()+height/2
        ax.annotate(percentage,(x,y))
```

For the first few graphs that this ran on, it returned integers for the percentage, which was fine.  However, I have noticed that on one of the graphs, they add up to 99, instead of 100.  Therefore, I believe that the code that I have is rounding up and down.  Normally, this wouldn't be problematic, but as this is for a dissertation, I need it to be spot on.

Unfortunately, I cannot see any way that I can ensure that the returned number is a float instead of an integer.

Comment: rounding all but one, then calculate the last one as `100-sum(others)`.

Comment: Have you checked what the percentages are, unrounded? There are probably a wide variety of cases where the percentages may add up to 99, e.g. 1/3, 1/3, 1/3 is 33%, 33%, 33%.

Comment: With `.0f` you define that you want no decimal places at all. So you basically always round down. If you want to allow decimal places you can increase this to e.g., `.2f` for 2 decimal places.

Comment: First, don’t get data from the graphics objects.  Surely you have the actual data available so just use that, otherwise you are trusting whatever bar does.  Second use “round” on the value before formatting in the string.  It’s still theoretically possible for this to not add up to 100, but it’s far less likely.

Comment: Thank you Marcel. That worked like a charm. Displaying exactly as I need